# Eclipse IDE is asking for update of ADT-Plugin

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using **Eclipse Ide** for android development. As I updated **Android SDK tool** to its newer version 24.1.2, Now Eclipse is showing an error that "***This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of ADT plug-in. Please update ADT plug-in***". I've checked update for ADT-Plugin several times but eclipse shows a popup with message "***No Updates were found***". what can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **manually** download Eclipse ADT plugin from Android, and then install it in Eclipse by importing downloaded zip into eclipse.

Complete procedure with steps can be found on this link

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Troubleshooting

**Update:**

By the way, above link will provide you **ADT-23.0.6.zip** not 24.1.2

There is a note on above link

> Note: If you have been using Eclipse with ADT, be aware that Android
>   Studio is now the official IDE for Android, so you should migrate to
>   Android Studio to receive all the latest IDE updates. For help moving
>   projects, see Migrating to Android Studio.

**Update 2**

Install **ADT-23.0.6.zip**, and it will work for **SDK Tools r24.1.2**.

http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

> This version of ADT is designed for use with SDK Tools r24.1.2. If you
>   haven't already installed SDK Tools r24.1.2 into your SDK, use the
>   Android SDK Manager to do so.